# Django REST Framework: serializing a model from callable to primary key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a serializer that looks like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    barid = serializers.IntegerField(source='get_bar')

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('id', 'barid',)
```

The callable `get_bar` returns a `Bar` object. I want the serialized output to `FooSerializer` to simply map `barid` to the primary key of the returned `Bar` object. When I run the above, however, what comes back is the unicode representation of `Bar` objects.

How do I get the primary key integer back? Thanks.

Comment: The following would also do the trick `barid = serializers.Field(source='get_bar.id')`.  Note that you can just use `serializers.Field` if it's a read-only field, since the typing doesn't matter if you're never updating it.

Comment: Thanks @TomChristie, that works great! Didn't know you could use the dotted notation on the callable like that. I'd mark this as the correct answer if you posted it below.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#serializermethodfield) to return a value, for example:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def getBarId(self, foo):
        return foo.get_bar().id

    barid = serializers.SerializerMethodField('getBarId')
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hamish, this works! Is this the "right" way? I'm wondering specifically if I there is a way to define a `BarSerializer` separately that reduces a Bar to its primary key, and then invoke that somehow in `FooSerializer`

Comment: I believe this is the best way. You *could* create a `BarSerializer` but it seems like a trivial case, and not really meaningful to have a serializer that simply returns an integer.